# Is QRandomGenerator deterministic across Qt versions?

Tags: c++, qt

In other words, if I create a `QRandomGenerator` with seed N in Qt version X, is it guaranteed to produce the same sequence as a `QRandomGenerator` created with the same seed N in Qt version Y?

The documentation only seems to imply determinism within a given version of Qt.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, excepted if you write *yourself* a [Mersenne Twister](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister) (or other similar PSEUDO-random generator) and know for sure that its output will be consistent across platforms (think about endianness, 32/64 bits, compiler optimizations, CPU speed, ...), you should **NEVER EVER** rely on a pseudo-random generator to deliver the same sequence on each run, whatever seed you used. `QRandomGenerator` isn't an exception.

Even without recompiling the binary, it ***may*** change if you change the execution platform (i.e. running it on another machine).

It's also why it isn't reliable to use a pseudo-random generator as a cryptographic system in itself.

Answer (score 0):

Everything you need to know is right there, in the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qrandomgenerator.html#details):

> QRandomGenerator may be used to generate random values from a
> high-quality random number generator. Like the C++ random engines,
> QRandomGenerator can be seeded with user-provided values through the
> constructor. When seeded, the sequence of numbers generated by this
> class is deterministic. That is to say, **given the same seed data,
> QRandomGenerator will generate the same sequence of numbers**. But given
> different seeds, the results should be considerably different.

And you can't say anything about different versions because they don't have to be compatible but I'd expect that within a major version you can count on it. Also you can check the implementation of each version you need to make sure it is the same.